# В чем различие transform.position = new Vector3() и transform.translate()

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть две строки:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + speed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
```

и

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

В чем отличие этих двух строк? Функционал у них абсолютно идентичный. Какую из этих двух строк мне использовать?

Comment: Если они, как вы и написали, работают одинаково (я не проверял), то в чём проблема? Просто используйте то что вам удобнее. Я бы выбрал то что короче, в данном случае.

Comment: Еще можно просто `transform.position += Vector3.right*speed*Time.deltaTime;`.

Comment: Так Translate - это и есть более короткая замена. Телепортация на указанный вектор. @KuzCode написал не очень практично в целом, но абсолютно точно в данном (!) случае: `Я бы выбрал то что короче`